# Rails 3 view helper undefined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of trying to install this view helper:

https://github.com/lwe/page_title_helper

I've followed the installation instructions but I think I must be missing something or the instructions assume I know something I don't (I'm new to Rails).

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `page_title'
```

The instructions say add 'page_title' to my views.

My translations follow. Note: I added the translation to several scopes for testing purposes.

```
# en.yml:

en:

  devise:
    sessions:
      new:
        title: "Sign In!"

  user_sessions:
    new:
      title: "Sign in!"  

  app:

    user_sessions:
      new:
        title: "Sign in!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try putting something like `page_title = 'my title'` in your view ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The installations says just add translations after I've added the 'page_title' to my view. All I have is <title><%= page_title %></title> as per instructions.

Comment: Just updated my question with the translations. I tried to define the translation on several different scopes to be sure. I'm using devise and currently testing on my sign in page.

Comment: Devise will be trickier. Try with one of your basic controllers first... The plugin depends on the controller structure, which you'll have to look up with devise controllers...